# real time indexing of live data stream

Tags: search, real-time, sphinx

Let us say, I am maintaining an index of a lot of documents. I want to update the index for newly arriving data to make it as real time as possible. What kind of indexing tool do I need to look at ? I have looked at Sphinx and Lucene and from previous posts, they are recommended for real time indexing.

The delta indexing mechanism used in Sphinx looks like a pretty neat idea.

Some questions I have are

1) How quickly can the document be searchable once it arrives ?
2) How efficient is the index merge process ? (merging the delta index and the main Index)

I understand these are very general questions and I wanted to get an idea if using Sphinx would be the right way to go about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx have [real-time indexes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rt-indexes) which allow add/update/delete indexes on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Apache Solr (NRT)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch) and [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) for real-time implementations using Lucene. You can look at some [benchmarks](http://engineering.socialcast.com/2011/05/realtime-search-solr-vs-elasticsearch/).